# OAS 3.0 Using polymorphism in Azure API management wont show schema in Developer Portal

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, apim

I'm using polymorphism in OAS 3.0 in Azure APIM. In case when using for example oneOf or anyOF in swagger, it will generate documentation and we can explore all schemas that are referenced inside anyOf/oneOf. So when i click on one of reference, it will expand it schema

Pic of swagger schema

[image: 1]

But in Azure APIM, documentation generated in Developer Portal, oneOf/anyOf shows only links to all references , but we can not press any of the links to see actual schema of those references.

Pic of Azure APIM Developer Portal

[image: 2]

Is there any solution for this?